# Optional parenthesis on function calls in PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP, and I accidentally forgot the parenthesis in `Echo 'Example'`

I'm curious as to why this worked, the only time I've seen this allowed was in SML, where the reason was that "All functions take only one item as a parameter, and that can be a tuple (A grouping of values)"

Is it similar to that reason? Or some other reason? I'm mostly interested for the sake of knowing if it conveys something more about the language... or if it is as simple as "Single argument functions do not need parenthesis"

I'm going to test what `func1 func2 func3 "test argument"` will do next... or even if it is possible! Any input on the order it will take would be a added pleasure.

Comment: `echo` is not actually a function; it is a *language construct,* so you are not required to use parentheses with it.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php.

Comment: So, it is basically just because? .... That seems silly.

Comment: Well, it's not a function.  You wouldn't expect to have to use parentheses for every keyword in the language, would you?  That() would() be() *really()* silly().

Comment: "So, it is basically just because? .... That seems silly." – Seriously? You are surprised over encountering something that doesn't make sense **in PHP**?

Comment: Similarly, `include`, `include_once`, `require`, and `require_once` are language constructs, and not functions. `include 'someScript.php';` is perfectly valid, but you still see it written a lot as `include ('someScript.php');` for some strange reason.

Comment: Those make sense but, echo is more akin to print, I don't know, it just seems odd, it feels like this language was just cobbled together, it feels like it lacks a distinction between elements of it's language.

Comment: @Sean_A91 Print does not require parentheses either. And yes you are correct about language being cobbled together, although this example is mostly OK compared to what you are going to encounter later. Happy learning! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, whenever you are not sure about a PHP functionality, check the official documentation.

Specific to your question, the official documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Exactly as it was correctly pointed out by one of the commentators and as it says in the documentation:

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.